# Entity Framework 6 Lazy loading with Angular

Tags: angularjs, entity-framework

Hi i have a issue with lazy loading using Entity Framework 6 and angular together.

When i call my server api from a angular service i often get a response where the customer, employee and service objects that gets lazy loaded returns null.

```
appointmentService.getTodaysAppointments().success(function(data) {
                    vm.appointments = data.appointments;                       
                });
```

**Here is how my json response look like:**

```
[
  {
    "customer": null,
    "employee": null,
    "service": null,
    "startDate": "2014-09-10T15:00:00",
    "endDate": "2014-09-10T16:00:00",
    "typeOfAppointment": 1,
    "isDeleted": false,
    "creationTime": "1900-01-01T00:00:00",
    "creatorUserId": 10,
    "id": 3494
  }
]
```

This is because Entity Framework haven't processed the object before it gets sent to the client.

Is there any way to solve this without removing the lazy loading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use the `Include` linq extension for loading data that you require in the `getTodaysAppointments` server implementation

```
dbContext.Appointments.Single(wherecondition)
 .Include(a=>a.customer)
 .Include(a=>a.employee)
 .Include(a=>a.service)
 .ToList()
```

Comment: Ty for this, understands now that there is no need for med to use lazy loading.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to not use lazy loading for queries like this. It is bad for performance, because you are doing multiple queries to DB instead of one. If you want to return data from related tables always use Include.

```
context.Appointments.Include("Customer").Include("Employee")
```

Comment: Ty, followed your advice not to use lazy loading.